# Securing builds on Hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We have an enterprise Hudson setup wherein I want to restrict the ability to trigger new builds to logged in users only. I do not have access to "manage Hudson" but I do have enough karma to create/edit jobs.

I tried adding "users" to the "job-based security" list and unchecked build rights from "Anonymous", but that doesn't seem to work for me. Is there a catch-all group for logged in users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "catch all" group for logged in users is `authenticated`.

However if `authenticated` have build permissions on global configuration (through manage Hudson), unchecking them on per-job will not remove permissions. These are  "allow" permissions and are cumulative, there are no "deny" permissions.

If you really want to restrict a job from being run by others, you can make a "password" type parameter in the job, and fail the job if that value is not something that's expected... but of course any admin with "configure" permission on your job could see it.